# Are static variable truly "global" (system-wide) in Android?

Tags: android, global, sandbox, static-variables

*A quick note at the very beginning to avoid false duplicates: There are tons of questions here about when static variables get cleared and how long they live. This is not what I'm asking about here.*

If I have a static variable in a program on a PC and I launch two different copies of the program, then each copy will usually run in its own sandbox with its own private values for its static variables. So, they are not system-wide global (not sure if that is good terminology here).

Are there situations in Android where I can have multiple "instances" (word used loosely) of a static variable around? I don't think it's possible to have multiple copies of an Activity running in parallel in different sandboxes (although I'm not certain of this), but how about ConentProviders, IntentServices, or any other class that Android might randomly instantiate from potentially other processes?

Or, phrased differently, if I have a class with a static variable, am I guaranteed that every single instance of the class existing on the same device at the same time has access to the exact same static variable value?

Comment: Maybe you can make use of the SharedPreference in this case, not sure though

Comment: @Virthuss SharedPreferences will probably work (if used right), but if I understand correctly, all writes to SharedPreferences go directly(?) to disk. Given that most Android devices use Flash memory for permanent storage with limited write-cycles, I would like to avoid disk-use whenever I can (not to mention that it's quite slow...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static fields are accessible to all the classes running in the same process. If the Service, Application, BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvider or Activity is running in a separate process then it will have a different memory space, thus won't see static fields from the other processes. You can force a component to run on another process by specifying its' it in the AndroidManisfest (e.g. android:process="string" http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)

Comment: Is the reverse also true? I.e. if I specifically specify a process, for example for a BroadcastReceiver, can I rely on the fact that all instances of this BroadcastReceiver will see the same static variables?

Comment: Yes. Because they will run on the same process, thus will have a shared memory space.

Comment: So, there is no such thing as two "instances" of the same process, or a process running in two different sandboxes, or android just splitting the load of one named process by creating two distinct processes with the same name (kind of like a threadpool or so)?

Comment: Simply, For accessing a static variable. You should have access to the class declaring it (Eg: Class.StaticVariable). If your BroadCastReceiver should access to the class for accessing the variable. If you need to share data among different processes, use contentProviders.

Comment: @MarkusA. There is no such thing, but keep in mind that the process can be killed by the system, thus lose its' static fields data. So, the second time BroadcastReceiver runs it might not have previously saved in static fields data.

Comment: K, perfect. Thanks. Sounds reasonable. Do you know if this is actually explicitly mentioned somewhere in the docs? It just seems to always be assumed to be obvious, but when coding, it's easy to shoot yourself in the foot by assuming that the seemingly obvious is actually what happens. And I've come across quite a few situations where the Android APIs aren't fully thought through either and break down for certain uncommon edge-cases...

Comment: Read through the Processes paragraph http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html It does not explicitly state anything about the static variables, but that's how the processes work in Java, and also in Android.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, I believe that static variable are not system-wide. It is only available in the instance of the application. So let say Activity A instantiate a static variable, Activity B will be able to use the static variable. Activity A and B belong to the same application. As long as the application doesn't close, the static variable should remained instantiated. However, as long as the application is close, the static variable will be killed and need to be reinstantiated. Note that I used the term **application** and **not activity**.

As for ContentProvider, Android normally will generate a directory for that particular application for all the data created by the application.